# How can I do this faster and more efficiently in R?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, dataframe

Make item random data

```
test <- matrix(runif(100, 0, 1), nrow = 20)
nr <- nrow(test)
mat = matrix(sapply(test, rbinom, n = 1, size = 1), nrow = nr)
```

Make name random data

```
testvec <- cbind( paste( "A", floor( 10 * runif(20, 0, 1) ), sep="" ) )
```

Make source data frame

```
dfrmORG <- data.frame( testvec, mat, c( 1:20 ) )
colnames(dfrmORG) <- c( "name", "item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5", "rkey" )
```

Duplicate name count

```
dfrmName <- as.data.frame( table( dfrmORG$name ) )
nrowUSR <- nrow( dfrmName )
```

Make target data frame

```
finalDFRM <- data.frame( name = character(nrowUSR), item1 = numeric(nrowUSR), item2 = numeric(nrowUSR),
                          item3 = numeric(nrowUSR), item4 = numeric(nrowUSR), item5 = numeric(nrowUSR) )
finalDFRM$name <- dfrmName[,1]
```

Logic

```
system.time({

for( i in ( 1 : nrow( dfrmORG ) ) ) {
    userKEY <- dfrmORG[ i, 1 ]
    finalDFRM[ c( finalDFRM$name == userKEY ), 2:6 ] <- finalDFRM[ c( finalDFRM$name == userKEY ), 2:6 ] * 0.9 + dfrmORG[ i, 2:6 ]
}

})
```

Logic too slow, how can I make it better ?

```
for loop
a <- a*x + b
```

I need sum, by name, items

```
result( finalDFRM )                     data( dfrmORG )
name item1 item2 item3 item4 item5      name item1 item2 item3 item4 item5
  A0  1.71 1.539   1.0  0.90   0.0        A0     0     1     0     0     0
  A4  2.71 0.900   1.9  1.71   1.9        A0     1     1     0     0     0
                                          A0     1     0     0     1     0
                                          A0     0     0     1     0     0
                                          A4     1     0     0     1     0
                                          A4     1     1     1     1     1
                                          A4     1     0     1     0     1
```

Comment: If you can you explain what you are trying to achieve with this sequence of code, that might make it easier to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use sapply

```
sapply(1 : nrow(dfrmORG), function(i){
userKEY <- dfrmORG[ i, 1 ]
finalDFRM[ c( finalDFRM$name == userKEY ), 2:6 ] <- finalDFRM[ c( finalDFRM$name ==    userKEY ), 2:6 ] * 0.9 + dfrmORG[ i, 2:6 ]
})
```

This usually is a lot faster than creating a for loop.

Comment: Have you timed it?  I doubt this would be much faster than the for loop, if at all.  Using vectorization might be preferred.

Comment: @RicardoSaporta I shall do a system.time. Few minutes

Comment: @RicardoSaporta   the sapply takes :    
`user  system elapsed 
0.104   0.000   0.106`
The for loop is only a bit slower:
   `user  system elapsed 
  0.108   0.000   0.110`

Comment: You might be interested in the packages `rbenchmark` and `microbenchmark` ;)

Comment: @RicardoSaporta I will have a look at those packages :0 thanks for the tip!